# How to force lm() and glm() functions not to refactor weights for linear regression?

Tags: r, linear-regression, glm, lm

I just want to run `lm()` and `glm()` for linear regression without refactoring weights, i.e., to utilize the weights just as they are specified. How can I do that?

It is known, but not documented, that the functions do refactor weights as they want.
https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:rma_vs_lm_lme_lmer
So, if you specify some weights `w` and, say, `w*100`, then you get the same p-values and confidence intervals. The problem is present for linear regression only, for logistic regression the weights are treated correctly.

Comment: Obligatory reading [here](https://notstatschat.rbind.io/2020/08/04/weights-in-statistics/), `lm` uses *precision* weights whereas for logistic regression (depending on exactly how you provide them) you're most likely talking about *frequency* weights. These are not the same & it's not clear what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Furthermore, it **is** documented exactly what these functions do: "Non-NULL weights can be used to indicate that different observations have different variances", compare that to the explanation I linked above. `glm` additionally specifies that "For a binomial GLM prior weights are used to give the number of trials when the response is the proportion of successes".

Comment: @PBulls Thank you for your response. I want to use frequency weights in linear regression. Can I do that?

Comment: Not directly as far as I know, it should be pretty straightforward to write a helper function that first duplicates each record `weight` times and then fit that.

Comment: @PBulls What if I want to use frequency weights which are noninteger?

Comment: @PBulls Besides, https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:rma_vs_lm_lme_lmer shows that `lm` uses rescaled frequency weights, not precision weights, strictly speaking.

Comment: Compute the coefficients by hand, using WLS formulation and compare the results to lm.

Answer (score 2):

First, a correction: `lm` and `glm` **do not** rescale the weights (you can check the code), it's just that the overall mean of the weights doesn't affect the answers for linear regression (as it shouldn't).  The mean of the weights gets absorbed into the scale parameter -- you can see that the estimated residual standard error changes.

If you want to get 10 times smaller variances as a result of multiplying all the weights by 10, or similar, one way to do this is to use `lm` or `glm` and then divide the standard errors by the mean of the weights.  Or, if you are using `glm` you can specify a different residual standard error to the `summary` functions (this is the best approach in the problem you linked to, where the issue is that an absolute scale parameter is *known* and doesn't have to be estimated)

Alternatively, if your weights are integers you can do

```
expanded_data <- data[rep(1:nrow(data), data$weights), ]
```

to repeat each observation as many times as its weight.

There aren't many statistical applications for this in linear regression, so it's not built in.

If you have a generalised linear model that has a *fixed* scale parameter (such as Poisson or binomial), the overall scale of the weights **does** affect the standard errors (as it should), but if you start estimating the scale parameter (eg with `quasibinomial` or `quasipoisson`) it doesn't.